# tables which are affected by the save button of magento admin panel?

Tags: category

I would like to know which tables are affected by the save button im trying it into magento admin panel, and i wanna know it cuz i have to know wich are this tables in my data base

please help me as soon as possible

Comment: Which save button? There are many in the admin panel, so the current answer is **ALL**.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Magento.SE! As it stands your question lacks clarity and may be closed. However, I will take a shot anyhow.

The correct answer is **none.** The **button itself** does nothing.

Buttons in the admin panel only redirect the end-user's browser to a controller action. In fact, the button itself doesn't actually do anything at all. The button has an `onclick` event, which executes a javascript method that posts data to a given controller action. *The controller action* is the important component here.

Once you visit the appropriate controller action a few things happen. Depending on the type of action you're executing it will validate that you have posted correctly formatted data. After that it executes a particular action which is specific to the implementation details of that method.

For instance, a massDeleteAction will likely take an array of ids which are to be removed from a specific table or tables. This, again, is an implementation detail and one could not say concretely **which tables are affected by a particular button.**

I hope that helps.

Comment: Especially if you delete an item that has a Foreign Key delete cascade, the original item can invisibly affect a dozen tables without a single reference to them in the original code that started the process.

Answer (score 0):

Though your questions seems so general and unclear, it would be nice if I show you an example. That will give you a better idea if you read my answer along with the answer that my friend @PhilipWinkle's answer.

So consider `save` button inside `Catalog  >  Manage Products`. Button appears when you select any product that available in grid to edit. When you inspect the button, you will see this code

```
<button id="id_ce1fca3117ef90651dcd0d99dec49de5" class="scalable save" style="" onclick="productForm.submit()" type="button" title="Save">
```

The part we interested in is the `onclick`. In invokes a function. So when the button clicked, the function will get triggered. Now the object `productForm` is defined in the same template itself and it looks like this

```
var productForm = new varienForm('product_edit_form', 'www.mydomain.com/admin/catalog_product/validate/id/172/key/89ff0c692abf0bb4e0896443bfa83d02/');
```

Remember this is a javascript object. You need to look on the the second argument that `varienForm` holds. It appears like this `www.mydomain.com/admin/catalog_product/validate/id/172/key/89ff0c692abf0bb4e0896443bfa83d02/`. So this is the url that is going to process when `save` button get clicked.  Let us refactorize this url. From this url, you can effectively trace which controller is going to process

```
www.mydomain.com/ - Base url

admin - frontname; Mage_Adminhtml holds this frontname

catalog_product - controller name; converts to Catalog/ProductController.php

validate - action name; converts to validateAction().
```

In effect magento will process `validateAction` that is defined inside `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php`. Now take a look on that method and check what that method does. It will give you an idea.

As philip said, the method do not going to say anything explicitly about tables that are going to alter. Since those processess are defined in Model section and are extremely complex to dig out.

Hope that gives you a better idea !

Next time come with a good question. :)